# Compare columns in 2 SQL tables

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to write my first c# app. And don't know how to compare 2 columns to calculate another field

This is table 1 (`Prediction` table):

```
Col A                  Col B 
--------------------------------------------
Prediction Home team   Prediction Home Score 
Liverpool              5
Arsenal                2
```

And this is table 2 (`Result` table)

```
Col A                  Col B 
----------------------------------------
Actual Home team       Actual Home Score 
Liverpool              5
Arsenal                1
```

I would like to compare the 2 columns b so if both same score then 5 points or 0 points if not matched.

Comment: You've stated what you want to do but not what you're actually expecting. you've tagged c# and sql - which are you expecting an answer for? This sounds like you need a SQL Query, so what is the c# relevance?

Comment: its a c# application  which im using a sql db.  i thought i would need to do a stored procedure?

Comment: if the Actual home score = predicted home score then i have a points (int) column which i want to be updated with 3 points  . if they dont match then  0 points

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for confusion. tied myself up in knots trying to find what to do.,

Comment: my prerdictions table has a column called points , which i want to update with 5 points if home score in table A = home score in table B

Answer (score 0):

The SQL part is this, as for the C# part we will need more details

```
CREATE TABLE prediction
(
prediction_home_team VARCHAR(100),   
prediction_home_score INT
);

CREATE TABLE result
(
actual_home_team VARCHAR(100),   
actual_home_score INT
);

INSERT INTO prediction (prediction_home_team, prediction_home_score) VALUES ('Liverpool', 5), ('Arsenal', 2);
INSERT INTO result (actual_home_team, actual_home_score) VALUES ('Liverpool', 5), ('Arsenal', 1);

/*
 * 
 * QUERY:
 * 
 */ 

SELECT prediction.prediction_home_team Team,
       prediction.prediction_home_score PredictedScore,
       RESULT.actual_home_score ActualScore,
       CASE 
        WHEN prediction.prediction_home_score = result.actual_home_score THEN 5
        ELSE 0
       END Points        
FROM prediction 
JOIN result ON result.actual_home_team  = prediction_home_team
```